# Powershell robocopy renaming files on error

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to copy files from a Directory with all it's subdirectories and files. As I already found out, that can be done easily with robocopy.

```
robocopy $source $dest $arg $logfile_temp
```

My Problem is, that there are some files (mostly *.png-files*) in the Source-Directory which contain a `":"` in their Name, because they are located at a Linux-Server (contain a timestamp).

Now, I want to robocopy all files to another Directory, and everytime an error occurs, because of that `":"` in the Name, the files should be copied to a Temp-Location, be renamed (`":"` --> `"."`) and then be copied to the Destination-Directory (so the orignial files basically stay untouched).

I would be awesome if someone could answer this question :)

Comment: So what i would do is to first solve your issue trough powershell and then do a robocopy of your files. So i would use powershell to rename the files that contain ":" and afterwards copy them to their new location. What you are trying to do is making things harder than they need to be imo.

Comment: But the original files should not be changed. I would have to create a copy of every file and rename that one. But how am i able to keep the original path too? Because the copied files need to be in the same path as on the Source-Directory?

Comment: The thing is, a windows system does not allow \/:*?"<>| in it's filenames. So you can't first copy it and then rename it. It will not allow you to do that (as far as i know at least) .

Comment: My idea is to copy the file on the Linux-Server to a Temp-Directory. I could the rename the file and copy it to my local Directory? But i dont really know how to do that in Powershell.

Comment: `md TEMPDIR; robocopy $source TEMPDIR ...; <rename files in tempdir>; robocopy TEMPDIR $dest ...`

Comment: That is actually a good idea, just copy all the files to a Temp-Directory and not just the files with a ":" in it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would rename your files at the path they are sitting at:

```
gci 'C:\temp\stack' |  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ':','.' } -whatIf
```

The -whatif parameter will do as if. If you remove it, it will do the actual renaming of the files.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to rename the files before, but wasn't able to iterate through all the files and keep the original directory.

Comment: If your problem is solved than please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

My final Script Looks like this:
First I initialize some variables:

```
$source = "..."
$temp = "..."
$dest = "..."
$arg = "..."
$logfile_temp = "..."
$logfile_dest = "..."
```

Then I copy all files to a Temp-Directory:

```
robocopy $source $temp /e /Log+:$temp\copyLog.txt
```

After that, I iterate through all the files in my Temp-Directory and search for files with a ":" in their Name:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | where {! $_.PSIsContainer} |   
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '#','.'}
```

Finally, I can copy those files/directories into my Destination-Directory.

```
robocopy $temp $dest /e /Log+:$dest\copyLog.txt
```

Also, I am logging the output of the process into "copyLog.txt".